# In CakePHP, why is my debug function NOT displaying the object like var_dump?

Tags: cakephp

For some reason, when I `var_dump` it shows the objects data in the variable, but it just shows nothing when I use CakePHP's `debug`. Why is that?

Using debug I only get this much, but there is a LOT of stuff in the object when I use var_dump:

Current setting for debug:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Doesn't work:

```
debug($account);
```

Output:

```
object(Recurly_Account) {

}
```

Works:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($account);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
object(Recurly_Account)#31 (6) {
  ["_values":protected]=>
  array(12) {
    ["adjustments"]=>
    object(Recurly_Stub)#34 (4) {
      ["objectType"]=>
      string(11) "adjustments"
      ["_href":protected]=>
      string(49) "https://api.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1/adjustments"
      ["_client":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_links":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["billing_info"]=>
    object(Recurly_Stub)#35 (4) {
      ["objectType"]=>
      string(12) "billing_info"
      ["_href":protected]=>
      string(50) "https://api.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1/billing_info"
      ["_client":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_links":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["invoices"]=>
    object(Recurly_Stub)#36 (4) {
      ["objectType"]=>
      string(8) "invoices"
      ["_href":protected]=>
      string(46) "https://api.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1/invoices"
      ["_client":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_links":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["subscriptions"]=>
    object(Recurly_Stub)#37 (4) {
      ["objectType"]=>
      string(13) "subscriptions"
      ["_href":protected]=>
      string(51) "https://api.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1/subscriptions"
      ["_client":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_links":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["transactions"]=>
    object(Recurly_Stub)#38 (4) {
      ["objectType"]=>
      string(12) "transactions"
      ["_href":protected]=>
      string(50) "https://api.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1/transactions"
      ["_client":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_links":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["account_code"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["state"]=>
    string(6) "active"
    ["email"]=>
    string(20) "test1@test.com"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(7) "test"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(3) "test"
    ["hosted_login_token"]=>
    string(32) "19415f3937cd6079c96e5141fe99bc49"
    ["created_at"]=>
    object(DateTime)#39 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2012-06-09 18:49:02"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(2)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(1) "Z"
    }
  }
  ["_unsavedKeys":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_errors":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_href":protected]=>
  string(37) "https://api.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1"
  ["_client":protected]=>
  object(Recurly_Client)#27 (2) {
    ["_apiKey":"Recurly_Client":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_acceptLanguage":"Recurly_Client":private]=>
    string(5) "en-US"
  }
  ["_links":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: When, how and where is this happening? Where's your code? We need specifics if we're to help.

Comment: Updated! Added all the output.

Comment: I've never seen an instance where debug doesn't work, that's very strange. Hmm..have you tried `pr($account)` instead of `debug($account)`?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking if I might have messed up a setting that I don't know about, so I posted it on SO. `pr` works beautifully. I don't even know how to go about this to see what's wrong.

Comment: Did you check your logs, maybe there's a clue somewhere, a suppressed error or something like that? If there nothing there, I give up, and maybe you should too :)

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary. I want to fix it and know what's wrong! I can always just install a fresh CakePHP.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, at least you'll know if there is a problem on your server, or just that single cake deployment, and then take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the values being printed with `print_r` for *non-standard* encoding characters.

Comment: The question was NOT about print_r(). Please read questions more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

That is something I recently fixed for CakePHP 2.3 (PHP 5.3+ is required).

Before, you would only see public properties of the object. With the current 2.3 head and my enhancements you will see also all protected and private properties (using Reflection - which print_r can provide natively by the way).

You can see the ticket here: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/3095-enable-debuggerexportvar-to-display-protected-and-private-class-properties#ticket-3095-3